# How to stop fan oscillation

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans, vibration, wind

I have a false ceiling so the length of my fan **down rod** is about 1 and half feet.

Whenever fan runs ,the **rod keeps on oscillating** and turning the **hole of false ceiling bigger** through **friction** besides when **there's a wind** from outside then **the blades of fan hitting the false ceiling** causing unpleasant noise.

I have checked with the guys who did false ceiling and my own house electrician they don't have ideas to fix this.

[image]

Please [see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SdASpNm-Clej2tvvUhk5Wv5rnR7mC0YW/view?usp=sharing) the fan in action

Comment: How did you install that fan? Was the false ceiling constructed around the fan after the fan was installed?

Comment: Part of the problem is that the fan is unbalance.  The mounting Where it comes though the ceiling will probably need to be made more ridged.

Comment: If wind makes the fan blades hit the ceiling then the fan is almost certainly installed too close to the ceiling to be able to work effectively.. A ceiling fan needs some clearance from the ceiling to be able to draw air in.

Comment: @jay613 - First built the false ceiling then installed the fan

Comment: @brhans - The distance is fair enough between fan wing and ceiling but the wind makes the fan hit the false ceiling and sometimes I see , it wobbles a lot.

Comment: @crip659 - Like you said , it's wobbling because of the fan rod. But I'm not sure how to fix this now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the wind is so strong that it's blowing the fan into the ceiling, close the window. That will stop the fan crashing into the ceiling.  There may be other benefits too.

Use the balancing kit and its instructions that came with the fan, or buy a balancing kit if you lost it, to balance it. That will stop the vibrations.

Make the hole in the false ceiling a little larger and install a decorative gasket or escutcheon. No matter how well you reduce vibrations, that will prevent the appearance of damaged drywall where the rod comes through the ceiling.

It appears as though you constructed that false ceiling around the rod after the rod was installed. I've never seen that done before. But I don't see why you couldn't firmly anchor the rod to the framework of the false ceiling. That might help with all of the problems that you stated.  As long as that framework is strong enough for the job, not just lightly constructed to support the decorative ceiling.

Comment: I think this should work. Thanks

Comment: I noticed that rod is slanted I mean to get the rod to center of false ceiling they have slanted it from the concrete ceiling. So balancing kit is not helping. Could you have a look at the video one more time and let me know you opinion also False ceiling framework is not strong enough to hold the fan.

Comment: I  cannot see how the false ceiling is framed or how it's connected to the house.  I don't understand how you installed that fan *after* the false ceiling was built.   You would have to connect it to the junction box through a small hole in the false ceiling?  I see now that the rod is not vertical.   I really can't start to help.  Also, the false ceiling will interfere with the air flow that the fan is designed to create.

Comment: @jay613 - There's a junction box inside the false ceiling.  so electric supply is there. They mistake they did is the centre point of square and and the rod position was not in straight line so they have slanted it I guess.